# Сумма элементов массива, расположенных после максимального элемента с вызовом функции

Tags: c, массивы, функции

Извиняюсь за большое количество вопросов последнее время.

Напишите программу, выделив каждую подзадачу в отдельную функцию.

Реализуйте программу, на вход которой подается одно из значений 0, 1, 2, 3 и массив целых чисел размера не больше 100. Числа разделены пробелами. Строка заканчивается символом перевода строки.

В зависимости от значения, функция должна выводить следующее:

0 : максимальное по модулю число в массиве.
1 : минимальное по модулю число в массиве.
2 : разницу между максимальным по модулю и минимальным по модулю элементом.
3 : сумму элементов массива, расположенных после максимального по модулю элемента (включая этот элемент). (sum)
иначе необходимо вывести строку "Данные некорректны".

```
#include <stdio.h>

int max_number(int arr[])
{
    int max, n_max;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    if (arr[i] > max)
    max = arr[i];
    n_max=i;
    }
return max;
}

int min_number(int arr[])
{
    int min;
    for (int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    if (arr[i] < min)
    min = arr[i];
    }
return min;
}



int main()
{
    int arr[5];
    int i,a;
    scanf("%d", &a);
    for (i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
    scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
    if (arr[i]<0)
    arr[i]*=-1;
    }
    int max=arr[0];
    int min=arr[0];
    int n_max=0;

    max = max_number(arr);
    min=min_number(arr);
    
    switch (a)
    {
    case 0:
    printf("%d",max);
    case 1:
    printf("%d",min);
    case 2:
    printf("%d", max-min);
    case 3: 
        for (i=n_max; i<10; i++)
        {
            sum+=arr[i];
        }
        printf("%d", sum);
    }
return 0;
}
```

Такой получился код, но не могу понять, как перенести case 3 в отдельную функцию.

Comment: Написать `int sum_number()` и считать... Вы, я смотрю, категорический противник инициализации локальных переменных, несмотря на то, что вам писали?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>

int min_index(int* arr, unsigned int size) {
    int idx = 0, min = abs(arr[0]);

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (abs(arr[i]) < min) {
            min = abs(arr[i]);
            idx = i;
            }

    return idx;
    }

int max_index(int* arr, unsigned int size) {
    int idx = 0, max = abs(arr[0]);

    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < size; i++)
        if (abs(arr[i]) > max) {
            max = abs(arr[i]);
            idx = i;
            }

    return idx;
    }

void task(int what, int* arr, unsigned int size) {
    switch (what) {
        case 0:
            printf("Max = %d\n", arr[max_index(arr, size)]);
            return;

        case 1:
            printf("Min = %d\n", arr[min_index(arr, size)]);
            return;

        case 2:
            printf("Max-min = %d\n",
                   arr[max_index(arr, size)] - arr[min_index(arr, size)]);
            return;

        case 3:
            int sum = 0;

            for (unsigned int i = max_index(arr, size); i < size;
                    ++i) sum += arr[i];

            printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);
            return;

        default:
            puts("Incorrect data");
        }
    }

int main() {
    int n, arr[100];
    printf("Number of elements: ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("arr[%d] = ", i);
        scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
        }

    for (int q;;) {
        printf("Action (-1 for quit): ");
        scanf("%d", &q);

        if (q == -1) break;

        task(q, arr, n);
        }
    }
```

Теперь, когда все сделано за вас, вы довольны?